# Why custom TEX command for labels does not work in MetaPost?

Tags: metapost

I'm trying to use text labels in MetaPost with TeX. The problem is that `-tex=...` option of MetaPost does not work.

This example works with `mpost test.mp`:

```
prologues := 3;
beginfig(1);
label.lrt("e", (0,0));
endfig;
end
```

This example does not work with `mpost -tex=csplain test.mp`:

```
prologues := 3;
beginfig(1);
label.lrt("é", (0,0));
endfig;
end
```

(`csplain` is provided by `texlive-lang-czechslovak` package)

Why `-tex=...` option of MetaPost does not work?

Comment: Use `btex é etex` or see 8.2 “Font Map Files” of the manual.

Comment: @HenriMenke `btex ... etex` works. Is it possible to use `pk` fonts? (I get this warning: `Warning: font lhr10 cannot be found in any fontmapfile!`)

Comment: I'm not a font expert but don't `pk` fonts only have 128 slots?  I don't think they have `é` encoded.  Also if you're not using `btex ... etex` MetaPost does not need a TeX engine and the parameter `-tex=csplain` is ignored.

Comment: @HenriMenke `pk` fonts can use 256 slots; for example, to use pk-variant of `é`, run `csplain test.tex` + `dvips test` with the following `~/.dvipsrc`: `p /dev/null`

Comment: @HenriMenke The number of slots is just a function of the encoding. T1 has 256. OT1 has 128. (Just examples.) That's just the TFM stuff. What kind of thing tells TeX what goes in the boxes the TFM describes is another matter.

Comment: @HenriMenke I do not understand what is T1 and OT1 (maybe because I do not use LaTeX?) - I use definition of font from TeXbook, so I do not understand what you are talking about.

Comment: @IgorLiferenko The encoding described in the TeXbook is known as OT1.  More about all the other encodings can be found in [`encguide.pdf`](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/base/encguide.pdf).  I guess they can also be used in Plain TeX but I don't know how.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want to escape to TeX you have to use a font which has this glyph, e.g. `texnansi-lmr10`.  It is important that the input file is encoded in ISO Latin 1.

```
prologues := 3;
defaultfont := "texnansi-lmr10";
beginfig(1);
label.lrt("é", (0,0));
endfig;
end
```

It is probably easier to just typeset the labels with TeX by using (as you showed in the question) `mpost -tex=csplain test.mp`.  In this case the file must be encoded in UTF-8.

```
prologues := 3;
beginfig(1);
label.lrt(btex é etex, (0,0));
endfig;
end
```

For more info see chapter 9 “Traditional labels and annotations” of Toby Thurston's excellent “Drawing with MetaPost” ([PDF](https://github.com/thruston/Drawing-with-Metapost/raw/master/Drawing-with-Metapost.pdf)).